# NEST with ElasticSearch System.net.WebException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, elasticsearch, nest

I'm developing in ASP.net and currently using the NEST plugin.  I have an entity framework data base model and elastic search can't seem to establish a connection:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:52009");
ConnectionSettings elasticSettings = new ConnectionSettings(uri);
ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(elasticSettings);
ConnectionStatus connectionStatus;
Debug.WriteLine(client.TryConnect(out connectionStatus)); // prints FALSE
    elasticSettings.SetDefaultIndex("name");
```

I believe it's due to an error connection settings because this prints out in my debugger:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

But I'm not given any more error details other than that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that ElasticSearch is working correctly?

I know all the examples use port 9200 and you are using port 52009.

If you browse to

```
http://localhost:52009/
```

to you see the following json:

```
{
  "ok" : true,
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Whiplash",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "0.90.2",
    "snapshot_build" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.3.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: But I know that elastic search isn't working because I keep getting System.Net.WebException whenever I try to establish a connection for ElasticSearch.  Also I changed the port to 9200 and same result.

Comment: Did you get the result of "ok": true when browsing to the url in your web browser.  If not, the ElasticSearch service may not be running currently.